# While in a Array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

hope someone can help me.
I try to write a Import Script for Articles in my Shopsystem.

For this edit the basic Code from the Wiki of the Shopsystem.

Here look

```
$updateArticle = array(
   'configuratorSet' => array(
        'groups' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Farben',
                'options' => $farbenarray
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Größe',
                'options' => $sizearray
            ),
        )
    ),
    'taxId'      => 1,
    'variants' => array(
        array(
            'isMain' => true,
            'number' => 'turn',
            'inStock' => 15,
            'additionaltext' => 'L / Black',
            'configuratorOptions' => array(
                array('group' => 'Size', 'option' => 'L'),
                array('group' => 'Color', 'option' => 'Black'),
            ),
            'prices' => array(
                array(
                    'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                    'price' => 1999,
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'isMain' => false,
            'number' => 'turn.1',
            'inStock' => 15,
            'additionnaltext' => 'S / Black',
            'configuratorOptions' => array(
                array('group' => 'Size', 'option' => 'S'),
                array('group' => 'Color', 'option' => 'Black'),
            ),
            'prices' => array(
                array(
                    'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                    'price' => 999,
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'isMain' => false,
            'number' => 'turn.2',
            'inStock' => 15,
            'additionnaltext' => 'S / Red',
            'configuratorOptions' => array(
                array('group' => 'Size', 'option' => 'S'),
                array('group' => 'Color', 'option' => 'Red'),
            ),
            'prices' => array(
                array(
                    'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                    'price' => 999,
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'isMain' => false,
            'number' => 'turn.3',
            'inStock' => 15,
            'additionnaltext' => 'XL / Red',
            'configuratorOptions' => array(
                array('group' => 'Size', 'option' => 'XL'),
                array('group' => 'Color', 'option' => 'Red'),
            ),
            'prices' => array(
                array(
                    'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                    'price' => 999,
                ),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Now i wan't to replace all the Variant Array with a While request.

Replace all like this

```
array(
            'isMain' => true,
            'number' => 'turn',
            'inStock' => 15,
            'additionaltext' => 'L / Black',
            'configuratorOptions' => array(
                array('group' => 'Size', 'option' => 'L'),
                array('group' => 'Color', 'option' => 'Black'),
            ),
            'prices' => array(
                array(
                    'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                    'price' => 1999,
                ),
            )
        ),
```

With a like a request like that ( i know thats don't work but i hope you understand what i like to do)

```
if ($resultat = $db->query('SELECT * FROM cache_article ORDER by id WHERE artikelnummer = "'.$herstellernummer.'"')) {
  while($daten = $resultat->fetch_object() ){


// WHILE THE ARRAY CODES







array(
            'isMain' => true,
            'number' => $daten->artikelnummer,
            'inStock' => 1,
            'additionaltext' => ''.$daten->size.' / '.$daten->color.'',
            'configuratorOptions' => array(
                array('group' => 'Size', 'option' => $daten->size),
                array('group' => 'Color', 'option' => $daten->color),
            ),
            'prices' => array(
                array(
                    'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                    'price' => $daten->price,
                ),
            )
        ),







// END THE ARRAY Codes


}
}
```

How i can do that correct so that works?
Please give me a Example for the request and how i can integrate that.

Sorry for my bad english! -.-

Thank You

Comment: UPDATE :) Please help, thanks.

Comment: What is `$daten`'s result when you `print_r();`?

Comment: you see the result in the while i need this fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand you.What you need is to store the generated arrays inside another, like this:

```
while(...        
    $arrayOfArrays[] = Array(...
```

That is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).
Basically `$variable[]` appends an element to the end of the array, but if the array doesn't exists then it creates it first.

Comment: can you give me a example who works with my code on the front? I hope so i can understand it better. Thank you!

Comment: So i try that but its don't work. I think the Problem is there a more arrays in arrays... -.- please help